# OS X Gatekeeper bypassed when application is owned by root

Tags: macos, security, file-permissions, code-signing

I understood that the purpose of OS X Gatekeeper was to block software without proper code signing. However, changing applications to be owned by root overrides this behavior.

1. Enable [Gatekeeper](https://support.apple.com/HT202491) and set it to accept apps only from the App Store.
2. Download an unsigned application from the internet (e.g. [Transmission](https://transmissionbt.com) which is [GPL licensed](https://github.com/transmission/transmission) and safe).
3. Attempt to open the app. It should fail with a warning.
4. Change the application's owner to `root`. E.g.
    `$` `sudo chown -R root /Applications/Transmission.app`
    It should now be able to be started without any warnings.

Is this intended behavior? Can an application be changed to warn again, even after being owned by root? Would that be more unsafe than letting the user own the application?

Comment: Which OS X, specifically ?

Comment: Just did this on El Capitan and it does the same as described by OP

Comment: @Tetsujin 10.11.1 (15B42)

Comment: @ᴢᴠᴇɴᴘᴇʀ it also implies that if I am logged in as **root** then Gatekeeper or Software Integrity Protection can be bypassed. Weird :/

Comment: @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like I thought they were separate systems? SIP still works for me at least, try `sudo mv /bin/sh /bin/sh.bak` for example.